# How to use custom HTTP headers with nmap?

Tags: nmap, burp-suite

I am trying a bbp program, and they allow requests only with some custom headers. So I was wondering if it is possible to add custom headers to nmap requests.

#### Things I tried:

I tried using burp proxy. I thought of adding headers using burp filters. I used this command

```
nmap -p10000 127.0.0.1 --proxy http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

(Here, I used port 10000 because I am listening on this using netcat to see request)

But I don't know why, but data is not going to burp, even if burp is closed, nmap returns result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The question doesn't make sense.

Depending on the chosen scan type, nmap sends raw TCP or UDP packets. By default, TCP packets with the `SYN` flag are sent, and nmap listens whether it returns a `SYN; ACK` (port is open) or a `RST` (port is closed).

TCP packets don't have HTTP headers. HTTP is a protocol that sits on top of TCP.

Comment: Now I see, why I am not seeing data. But still it is weird that nmap has "--proxy" option and working even when no proxy is on.

Comment: @ParveshMonu It's not weird at all. nmap checks if the proxy is there and works, and will use it if it works - if it doesn't, it tries to connect directly.

Comment: @ParveshMonu it's not weird at all. Please look up the documentation for how the proxy works and what it is used for (and what protocols it is used for). Just adding a proxy directive to the command does not magically route all traffic to the proxy.

Comment: Ok, Thanks MechMK1 and schroeder. This cleared my confusion.

Comment: This question makes sense if you are using nse scripts that do HTTP-related tasks.